# Complex ordering in Django

Tags: database, django, orm

I have a Django model for `Cat` which has a foreign key `Dog`. The `Dog` model has a date key `timestamp`. I want to order the cats, using `Cat.objects.order_by`, according to the timestamps of their respective dogs. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the double-underscore syntax.

```
Cat.objects.order_by('dog__timestamp')
```